# Determining the real roots of a polynomial within a specific range

Tags: java, root, polynomial-math, bisection

I am a  beginner in coding especially in java and I have tried plenty of times figuring how to find the real roots of a polynomial within a given range. The program is supposed to find all the real roots of the given polynomial the user provided. For example, the program should run as follows: 
Enter the degree: 3
Enter 4 coefficients: -6 11 -6 1
Enter the left and right endpoints: -10 10
Root found at: 1.00000 Root found at: 2.00000 Root found at: 3.00000.
Attached below is the format of my program.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class Roots{
    public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            double resolution=0.01;
            double tolerance=0.0000001;
            double threshold=0.001;
            double roots;
            System.out.print("Enter the degree: ");
            int degree =sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter "+(degree+1)+" coefficients: ");
            double[] C=new double[degree+1];
            for(int i=0; i<C.length;i++){
                    C[i]=sc.nextDouble();
            }
            System.out.print("Enter the left and right endpoints: ");
            double a=sc.nextInt();
            double b=sc.nextInt();
            if(poly(C,a)*poly(C,b)<0){
                    roots=findRoot(C,a,b,tolerance);
            }
    }
    }
    static double poly(double[] C, double x){
            int n=C.length-1;
            int K;
            double sum=0.0;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                    sum+=C[i]*(Math.pow((x-i),n));
            }
            return sum;
    }
    static double[] diff(double[] C){
            int n=C.length-1;
            int K;
            double[]D=new double[n];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                    D[i]=C[i]*(n-1);
            }
            return D;
    }
    static double findRoot(double[] C, double a, double b, double tolerance){
            //loops here
    }
```

}

Comment: Could you please tell more about the origin of the question? Were there any test cases supplied? Restrictions on the degree? Is "cheating" allowed, i.e., compute all roots including complex ones via Laguerres method and deflation and then filter out the ones inside the interval?

Answer (score 1):

One problem you have to solve is to capture the scenario where the interval is [-1,1] and the polynomial is x^2+a. Depending on the sign of a, you have two, one double or no solutions.

If you are going to reject this case by demanding alternating signs on the interval end points, so that the intermediate value theorem guarantees a root, then a first efficient root finding method is the Illinois variant of the regula falsi method.

Please also look up the evaluation of polynomials via the Horner scheme, using Math.pow is only recommended if you have a sparse polynomial like `x^100-3*x^37+5x-1`.

---

If you really want to find all roots in any case, then the best you can do is to subdivide the interval and exclude all subintervals containing no roots using inner root radius estimates. This is known as the [bisection-exclusion algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jco.2005.06.007). Eventually, the coefficient signs or a Sturm sequence will tell you if there are any roots inside the remaining small intervals.

---

Details for bisection-exclusion methods: They require Taylor shifts of the polynomial, i.e., to evaluate the coefficients of `p(x+h)` as a polynomial in h, which is an O(n^2) operation. The original exclusion algorithm recursively scans intervals [a,b] by shifting the polynomial to the midpoint x=(a+b)/2 and computing an inner root radius r. Then the same is applied to the intervals [a,x-r] and [x+r,b].

Description of the simple form of the exclusion algorithm at (http://algo.inria.fr/seminars/sem92-93/yakoubsohn.ps‎) (Postscript viewer required)

Comment: So I know how to program the bisection method, however, I need help subdividing the intervals using the method.

Comment: I was referring to a different bisection method, not the primitive one used as a constructive proof of the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

A probably sufficiently robust variant that will catch all but extremal cases is the following:

The interval to explore is [a,b]. The polynomial f(x) has degree d. Set `N=3+d*d`. (This may be subject to experimentation) and `h=(b-a)/N`.

Iterate over the points `x0=a+k*h`, k=0,1,...,N. Using this `x=x0` as initial point, perform the Newton iteration `dx=-f(x)/df(x), x=x+dx`. In addition to the usual checks for success, `abs(dx)<eps1`, `abs(f(x))<eps2*scale_f`, implement a check `2*abs(x-x0)>h` for failure that is triggered if the iteration moves more than h/2 away from the initial point, so that only close-by roots are found, if there are any.